# Plot hist with date index on x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have the following data:

```
            num_incidents
date                     
2014-01-01            208
2014-01-02            112
...                   ...
2018-03-30             67
2018-03-31             77
```

If I try to plot it using the default histogram method, I get the following output:

```
daily_incidents_df.hist()
plt.show()
```

[image]

While this is useful, I'd also like to plot something like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the source DataFrame contains:

```
            num_incidents
date                     
2014-01-01            208
2014-01-02            112
2015-02-02            100
2015-03-02            130
2016-02-02            130
2016-03-02            130
2011-02-02            170
2011-03-02            130
2018-03-30             67
2018-03-31             77
```

To compute yearly totals run:

```
s = df.num_incidents.groupby(df.index.year).sum()
```

Then to draw your picture, run:

```
ax = s.plot.bar(rot=0, width=0.9)
ax.set_xlabel('Year', fontsize=16)
ax.set_ylabel('Incidents', fontsize=16);
```

Note the `;` terminating the last instruction, to suppress
additional display concerning the last created drawing object.

Set *width* parmeter a little below *1.0*, to fill almost all space
with bars for each year.
For the above data I got the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a year column:

```
df['Year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df[['Year', 'num_incidents']].hist()
```

Comment: This is close, the only issue is that it gives a histogram with the number of days in a year (365), rather than the number of incidents